# Error code 5, ENCODING_ERR when saving an image from the application directory to the phone's image gallery

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to save an image from an ios application to the image gallery, so the user can share it.

My app is using ionic framework & ngCordova. I am trying to save the image like this:

```
      image = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/img/deck/" + card.image;          
      file_path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "wisdom.png";
      $cordovaFile.createFile(file_path, true).then(function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }, function(err) {
        alert('create error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      });          
      $cordovaFile.writeFile(file_path, image).then(function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }, function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
```

This gives an error code 5, ENCODING_ERR - when creating the file.  The write file does not give a success or fail error.  There is no image in the gallery. What should the path be to save the file? How should i send the image to the write method? Why am i getting an encoding error?

Comment: Hi I have the same. Were you able to solve it.

Comment: no, sorry. Ill update this with whatever workaround i end up with.

Comment: Thanks. Keep looking also at the following post, the author has indicated being busy with a tutorial, solving for encoding error. http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and already found a workaround for it. You may not need it anymore but for someone is looking for it.

Add these lines in your config:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />

<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
```

Also file url should start with **file:///...**